# No templates visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on a project on Vs2019 when I try to add a new item (a service based db in my case) nothing appears in the visual c# elements.
I tried reparing the version from the Vs installer and clearing the cache as well as reinstalling the templates and still nothing.

Comment: SQL Database projects are unrelated to C# projects. Please elaborate on what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: @Dai I am trying to add a new item ( a service based database which is a visual c# item)

Comment: What do you mean by "service-based database"? There is no C# project item template for whatever that is.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/q7SLFZI

Comment: Oh, that's just an old template-item for a SQL Server `LocalDb` database. It's obsolete. You should use SSDT instead.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IYsZJN1

Comment: I installed al the sql server data tools btw @Dai

Comment: and it doesn't show up in the installed section too